# jquery find element considering parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

How can I find an element considering parent node? Example:

```
<ul class="level-3">
     <li class="item-1">1</li>
     <li class="item-2">2</li>
     <li class="item-3">3</li>
</ul>
```

```js
var $ul = $('.ul');
console.log($ul.find('.item-1')) - // found - OK
```

if find

```
console.log($ul.find('.level-3')) - // not found - WHY ???
```

Comment: where is `.ul` in your code?

Comment: Are you looking for `.closest()` ? - The ul itself is `$("ul")`

Comment: Because, There's no descendants element having class `.level-3`

Comment: Where is the element `$('.ul')`? What exact output do you expect?

Comment: @AlinaOsipova, what you exactly wants to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming UL as element**

You are not able to find it as `level-3` is not the child of `ul`.

As per your current HTML, You need to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

*Code*

```
var $ul = $('ul'); 
$ul.filter('.level-3')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use soma kind of jQuery functions to do this:

**Closest**: find the anchestor element matches the selector.

> The .closest() method begins its search with the element itself before progressing up the DOM tree

**Parents**: walk the DOM tree looking for all parents that matches the selector.

**is**: check if the element match the selector.

```
$ul.closest(".level-3")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your point you don't have ".level-3" class. For simply you can use jquery to do this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        alert($("ul").find('.item-3').text());
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="level-3">
     <li class="item-1">1</li>
     <li class="item-2">2</li>
     <li class="item-3">3</li>
</ul>

<button id="btn1">Show level 3 Text</button>

</body>
</html>
```